# differentiate identical arrayLists

Tags: java

Suppose you have an  arrayList of arrayLists:

```
[[a,b,c] , [a,c,d] , [f,g,h] , [a,b,c]]
```

As you notice, arrayLists at position '0' and '3' are identical. So here comes the problem: i can't differentiate them. Any change i try to implement to first [a,b,c] is implementing to second [a,b,c] also. For example:

```
for(n=0; n<4; n++){
arrayList.get(n).add(0,String.valueof(n));
}
```

has outpout

```
[[0,a,b,c] , [1,a,c,d] , [2,f,g,h] , [0,a,b,c]]
```

Any idea to differentiate identical objects; Thank you in advance

Comment: My guts tell me that the first and forth element are not only equal, but they are the same object. You can verify this by calling `System.out.println(arrayList.get(0) == arrayList.get(3));` (should print `true`). If this is the case, then this is your problem. You have the same object multiple times in your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have added the same arrayList twice to the arrayOfArrayList.

If you want two copies of the same arrayList (but not the same), do

`arrayOfArrayList.add(new ArrayList(arrayList));` you wont have the problem anymore then.